# Ambiguous operator <<

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Record.h"

template<class T>//If I make instead of template regular fnc this compiles  
//otherwise I'm getting an error (listed on the very bottom) saying  
// that operator << is ambiguous, WHY?
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const T& obj)
{
    out << "Price: " 
        << (obj.getPrice()) << '\t'//this line causes this error
        << "Count: "
        << obj.getCount()
        << '\n';
    return out;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    vector<Record> v;
    v.reserve(10);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        v.push_back(Record(rand()%(10 - 0)));
    }
    copy(v.begin(),v.end(),ostream_iterator<Record>(cout, "\n"));
    return 0;
}

//Record class
class Record
{
    private:
        int myPrice_;
        int myCount_;
        static int TOTAL_;
    public:
        Record(){}
        Record(int price):myPrice_(price),myCount_(++TOTAL_)
        {/*Empty*/}
        int getPrice()const
        {
            return myPrice_;
        }

        int getCount()const
        {
            return myCount_;
        }
        bool operator<(const Record& right)
        {
            return (myPrice_ < right.myPrice_) && (myCount_ < right.myCount_);
        }
};

int Record::TOTAL_ = 0;
```

**Error 2   error C2593: 'operator <<' is ambiguous**

Comment: It might be because `getPrice()` is not defined for every type, hence template is not working

Comment: Can you post the exact error message? They usually tell you exactly why (albeit in the most round-about way possible, with templates)

Comment: @Cogwheel I've added ENTIRE error msg I'm getting.

Comment: ha Well that sure was useful, wasn't it? -_-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need to read the error message more carefully. As an alternative, consider breaking the statement up, something like this:

```
out << "Price: ";
out << (obj.getPrice());
out << "\tCount: ";
out << obj.getCount();
out << '\n';
```

When you do, you'll realize that what's really causing the problem is *not* where you try to print out `getPrice()`, but where you try to print out `"Price: "`.

The problem is arising because the compiler doesn't know whether to use the normal overload to print out the string, or to use the template being defined to print it out. The latter would cause infinite recursion, and it couldn't actually compile since it requires an object on which you can/could call `getPrice` and `getCount` to compile correctly -- but it has a signature that matches, so the compiler says it's ambiguous, and that's the end of that.

Comment: thank you for this explanation. So I'm guessing line number provided by compiler is wrong?

Comment: but what puzzels me why compiler didn't pick specialized version for string and int?

Comment: @A-ha: It's pretty typical for the compiler to list a line or two after the location of the real problem (usually when it gets to something that makes it clear that what was already processed had a problem). It can't pick one over the other because neither requires a conversion, so they're equally good matches.

Answer (score 9):

The concept behind `operator<<( ostream &, ... )` is that every class can have its own overload, handling that specific class in a way that make sense.

That means you get `operator<<( ostream &, const Record & )` which handles Record objects, and `operator<<( ostream &, const std::string & )` which handles standard strings, and `operator<<( ostream &, const FooClass & )` which handles FooClass objects. Each of these functions knows how to handle the object type it has been declared for, because each of them *requires* a different handling. (E.g. `getPrice()` / `getCount()` for `Record`, or `getFoo()` / `getBar()` for `FooClass`.)

Your template is trampling roughshod over the whole concept. By defining it as a template function (which would match *any* class), you not only collide with the many definitions of `operator<<()` already in the standard / your codebase, but all *possible* overloadings.

How could the compiler decide whether to use `operator<<( ostream &, const std::string & )` or your template? It cannot, so it throws up its hands in despair and gives up. That's what the error is telling you.

Comment: as I agree with you in general I can't agree with you when you're saying, and just wait a second and let me copy... and paste... o here we go "How could the compiler decide whether to use operator<<( ostream &, const std::string & ) or your template?" Well, can't compilator check for type of the argument and then pick the right template? The second point I would like to make is that compiler do not have problem (in this case) with picking right template because the error is caused by line inside this template as marked by me in my original post.

Comment: Well, Jerry's answer (which you accepted) doesn't say anything different: "The problem is arising because the compiler doesn't know whether to use the normal overload to print out the string, or to use the template being defined to print it out." That is what "ambiguos" means: Using the rules of the language, the compiler ends up with more than one `operator<<()` that would fit, and cannot decide which to use. Make no mistake, this is a *programming error*, not some kind of stupidity on behalf of the compiler. It cannot read minds; your code must be unambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of the error is that your templated overload is conflicting with another templated overload, and there is no reason to prefer one template to another:

```
template<class charT, class traits>
basic_ostream<charT,traits>& operator<<(basic_ostream<charT,traits>&, const charT*);

template <class T>
basic_ostream<char, char_traits<char> >& operator<< (basic_ostream<char, char_traits<char> >&, const T&);

//which one is preferable when you ask for: cout << "literal";?
```

(`ostream` should be a typedef for `basic_ostream<char, char_traits<char> >`.)

The whole idea of making your overload a template is questionable, seeing that the overload clearly cannot handle any other class than your Record.

There probably are techniques to allow you to provide a single templated overload for a number of unrelated Record-like classes with a little template metaprogramming (enable_if and traits), if that is the idea.